# Changing the CloseRequestFunction of a figure in a class

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

So I have a matlab class with a constructor like

```
function obj=MyClass(inputs)
        .
        .
        h=figure(ClosRquestFcn',@obj.test,,'Name','Progress','NumberTitle','off');
        .
        .
 end
```

My problem is that it does not detect the method test() in MyClass class. I have tried it without the 'obj.' prefix aswell, but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me to be a symptom of another problem.  Not sure if you copied your code exactly, but there are some typos in there.  If I make the toy object:

```
classdef testobj
  methods
    function testme(varargin)
      for ii=1:nargin
        if( isa(varargin{ii},'double') )
          disp( varargin{ii} );
          delete(varargin{ii});
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then instantiate the object and create a simple figure with a close function callback:

```
me = testobj
figure('CloseRequestFcn',@me.testme)
```

When I close the figure, it closes and then prints the handle number on the screen.

```
4
```

Try to just add the close function and make sure it executes as you expect.  If you have any `try` blocks, be sure to display any `catch` errors.